# definition of service [pg_servicename] not found on Windows

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis

I am running into issues trying to connect to a db using a service file from within QGIS.
Error is "Connection to databse failed. definition of service "pg_servicename" not found.

.pg_service.conf file looks like this:

```html
[pg_servicename]
host=127.0.0.1
dbname=pg_servicename
user=postgres
port=5432
password=samplepassword
```

While searching online, I found several suggestions on where to place this file.

- /AppData/postgresql
- /program files/postgresql/15/bin
- /program files/postgresql/15/etc

So far it fails to find the file. I also converted the file to Unix (Notepad++ > View > EOL > Unix)

I am new to Postgreql. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to set the environment variable `PGSERVICEFILE` to point to your service file.